# Logging Request/Response size in access_log of Nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to log request/response size(body+headers) in the access_log. Any idea how to do it in nginx? 
In apache we can do it using %I..%O...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use these 2 parameters in nginx.conf:

> log_format  perf            '$remote_addr $status - $request_length $bytes_sent'

According to documentation ( http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule) the `$request_length` is only the body of the request, but I have confirmed that it includes all headers (I have some GET requests with lots of cookies which have more than 1400 bytes in total). `$bytes_sent` is total number of bytes sent to the client (as opposed to `$body_bytes_sent` which is compatible with apache %B).

Comment: $body_sent is not a variable in nginx logging module

Comment: @user1559834 seems it is `$body_bytes_sent` now. Not sure if they changed it since my post in year 2012 or it was a typo.

Answer (score 17):

Taken from [ngx_http_log_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html):

> `$bytes_sent`: the number of bytes sent to a client
>
> `$connection`: connection serial number
>
> `$connection_requests`: the current number of requests made through a connection (1.1.18)
>
> `$msec`: time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution at the time of the log write
>
> `$pipe`: “p” if request was pipelined, “.” otherwise
>
> `$request_length`: request length (including request line, header, and request body)
>
> `$request_time`: request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution; time elapsed between the first bytes were read from the client and the log write after the last bytes were sent to the client
>
> `$status`: response status
>
> `$time_iso8601`: local time in the ISO 8601 standard format
>
> `$time_local`: local time in the Common Log Format

Answer (score 1):

**$request_length**: 
request length (including request line, header, and request body)

**$bytes_sent**:
response length (including header, and body)

**$body_bytes_sent**:
response length only include body.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).