# How to get response size using nginx post_action directive?

Tags: nginx

I am planning to limit user bandwidth. I came across `post_action` directive in core module and thinking if I can get response size served by `nginx` and send it to code using `post_action`.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` sets its `$body_bytes_sent` variable to the size of the HTTP response.

Comment: There's `$bytes_sent` too which includes headers. See this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/346857/44112

Answer (score 0):

There's a [built-in solution to limit user bandwith](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#limit_rate) in the `HttpCoreModule` of `nginx`. Let's say for example that you want to limit bandwith to 20kB/s:

```
set $limit_rate 20k;
```

Comment: I want to limit bandwidth per user per month